# How to close the parent cmd console window from within the script it's hosting?

Tags: windows, vbscript, cmd

I am using the following command in the registry to run a vbscript locally from Windows Explorer's context menu:

`cmd /T:1F /K "cscript.exe //nologo "C:\Some Path\Some Folder\MyScript.vbs" "%1""`

I am using the `/K` switch for 2 reasons: to keep the console window open in case of script errors, and to change the back and fore colors of the console (this is actually done with the `/T` switch, but for some reason that I don't understand, the colors revert to default when the `/C` switch is used.

My question: how can I close the host console window (attached to the "cmd.exe" process) on normal execution end? `WScript.Quit` obviously returns to the console prompt. I thought about a WMI query for Win32_Process based on CommandLine, but that doesn't work if the script is invoked multiple times with the same parameter (i.e. file). Is there a way to obtain the top most parent process's id for example, which I can then use to terminate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you can simply append `&&exit` to your command string:

```
cmd /T:1F /K "cscript.exe //nologo "C:\Some Path\Some Folder\MyScript.vbs" "%1"&&exit"
```

Note that your quoted arguments are not quoted because of the extra enclosing quotes. You might be better off with:

```
cmd /T:1F /K ^"cscript.exe //nologo "C:\Some Path\Some Folder\MyScript.vbs" "%~1"^&&exit^"
```

**Update**

The script engine does not set the exit code upon runtime errors - it leaves that task to the script writer. It does set a positive exit code if there is a syntax error. That is a very unfortunate design.

I think the easiest thing to do is to modify your VBS script to always exit with a negative value upon success: `WScript.Quit -1`. Then you can conditionally EXIT the console only if the exit code is negative.

```
cmd /T:1F /K ^"cscript.exe //nologo "C:\Some Path\Some Folder\MyScript.vbs" "%~1"^||if not errorlevel 0 exit^"
```

Comment: Hehh.. I don't know why I didn't think of this, maybe I was under the impression that `/K` would override any exit command. Anyways, works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: I'd use `&&` instead of `&`, so the `exit` will be skipped when the script returns with an error (i.e. a non-zero exit code).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - Good catch. I missed the "normal execution" constraint.

Comment: @Makaveli84 - Answer has been updated as per Ansgar's good suggestion.

Comment: Any ideas on how to incorporate a `TITLE` command to set the console's title to a "xyz" string? Right now, it displays the entire command line. I tried adding a `TITLE xyz` at the beginning, but it inserts the "xyz" before the command string.

Comment: @Makaveli84 - Same concept, but use `&` instead of `&&`: `cmd /T:1F /K ^"title xyz^&cscript ... ^&&exit^"`

Comment: @dbenham - That results in a "xyz - cscript //nologo..." title. I am trying to get a "xyz" title only.

Comment: @Makaveli84 - Ahh, I see. I think you may be out of luck on that one.

Comment: One minor nit: if the script exits because of a language error, cscript returns error code 0 and the script will appear to have succeeded.  The only way around this is for "normal exit" to return a fixed, non-zero value, and to check for that before exiting the command shell.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - Wow, that is unfortunate, and totally unexpected. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I don't know what's going on anymore.. Console doesn't stay even on && exit and any type of error (div by 0, "lang error")...

Comment: Well, I'm not sure, but it seems error code is always 0, no matter what the error. I replaced `&& exit` with `& if errorlevel 99 exit`, and I'm exiting the script with `WScript.Quit 99`, and all is well again, unless there's yet another caveat?!

Comment: @Makaveli84 - Yep, that should work. I updated my answer in a similar way, but I chose to use a negative value for success.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - Actually, runtime errors return 0, syntax errors return 1. But your general point and solution is still valid. I updated my answer and opted to use a negative code to indicate success.

Comment: @dbenham: good to know, thanks.  Luckily for me I typically return 1 from scripts to indicate an error, so I was already treating both 0 and 1 as error conditions, otherwise that could have caught me out!